# How to catch error while inserting data with SqlDataSource

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, sqldatasource

I have a SqlDataSource and a GridView.

What I want to do is, while the query is executed (i.e. for inserting a data), then after the data has inserted successfully, it should appear a message sounds: "The data deleted successfully". I've solved it by using GridView1_RowDeleted method.

Now the problem is, I want to catch the error while the query is failed to executed. If the query has failed to execute, then it should appear a message: "The data failed to insert.".

How to do it? I don't have an idea about this.

Need your help guys.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add a handler for the relevant event:  inserted, deleted. Then, in the handler look at the `SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs property Exception`. If it's not null then an
exception has occurred. For example if the selected command threw an
exception:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Exception != null)
   {
       // handle the exception
   }
}
```

--

Comment: hey it's worked!! :) . I've tried to change the handler become: `Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Updated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Updated` . Thanks a lot :)